# How can a Ruby C extension store a proc for later execution?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

Goal: allow c extension to receive block/proc for delayed execution while retaining current execution context.

I have a method in c (exposed to ruby) that accepts a `callback` (via `VALUE hash` argument) or a `block`.

```
// For brevity, lets assume m_CBYO is setup to make a CBYO module available to ruby
extern VALUE m_CBYO;
VALUE CBYO_add_callback(VALUE callback)
{
    if (rb_block_given_p()) {
        callback = rb_block_proc();
    }

    if (NIL_P(callback)) {
        rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "either a block or callback proc is required");
    }

    // method is called here to add the callback proc to rb_callbacks
}
rb_define_module_function(m_CBYO, "add_callback", CBYO_add_callback, 1);
```

I have a struct I'm using to store these with some extra data:

```
struct rb_callback
{
    VALUE rb_cb;
    unsigned long long lastcall;
    struct rb_callback *next;
};
static struct rb_callback *rb_callbacks = NULL;
```

When it comes time (triggered by an epoll), I iterate over the callbacks and execute each callback:

```
rb_funcall(cb->rb_cb, rb_intern("call"), 0);
```

When this happens I am seeing that it successfully executes the ruby code in the callback, however, it is escaping the current execution context.

Example:

```
# From ruby including the above extension
CBYO.add_callback do
    puts "Hey now."
end

loop do
    puts "Waiting for signal..."
    sleep 1
end
```

When a signal is received (via epoll) I will see the following:

```
$> Waiting for signal...
$> Waiting for signal...
$> Hey now.
$> // process hangs
$> // Another signal occurs
$> [BUG] vm_call_cfunc - cfp consistency error
```

Sometimes, I can get more than one signal to process before the bug surfaces again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while investigating [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878944/calling-io-operations-from-thread-in-ruby-c-extension-will-cause-ruby-to-hang/53654543#53654543).

As it turns out, I too was trying to use native thread signals (with `pthread_create`) which are not supported with MRI.

TLDR; the Ruby VM is not currently (at the time of writing) thread safe. Check out [this nice write-up on Ruby Threading](https://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/#threading) for a better overall understanding of how to work within these confines.

You can use Ruby's [native_thread_create(rb_thread_t *th)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/thread_pthread.c#L986) which will use `pthread_create` behind the scenes. There are some drawbacks that you can read about in the documentation above the method definition.  You can then run the callback with Ruby's [rb_thread_call_with_gvl](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/thread.c#L1531) method.  Also, I haven't done it here, but it might be a good idea to create a wrapper method so you can use `rb_protect` to handle exceptions the callback may raise (otherwise they will be swallowed by the VM).

```
VALUE execute_callback(VALUE callback)
{
    return rb_funcall(callback, rb_intern("call"), 0);
}

// execute the callback when the thread receives signal
rb_thread_call_with_gvl(execute_callback, data->callback);
```